# Why the class CqlStorage is not there in latest versions of apache-cassandra-X.X.X.jar

Tags: java, hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig, datastax

The class org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CqlStorage is a pig Cassandra driver.

This class is present in following Cassandra versions,

- 2.0.5 ( apache-cassandra-2.0.5.jar )
- 2.1.12 ( apache-cassandra-2.1.12.jar )

But it is missing in following latest releases

- 2.2.4 ( apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar )
- 3.0.0 ( apache-cassandra-3.0.0-alpha1.jar )

Not sure why it is discontinued and what is the alternative for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the JIRA about it here -- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10542

> Nobody's currently responsible for Pig code. As a result, there is nobody to fix the issues, or even fix the failing tests (of which we unfortunately have plenty). Those tests take time to run, constantly hang, and fail with cryptic errors that we don't know how to fix and don't have enough resources to investigate.
>   Thus I propose we deprecate Pig support in 2.2 and remove it in 3.0.

Comment: OK, I see this comment in 2.1  @deprecated use CqlNativeStorage instead. CqlStorage will be removed.   Can you recommend the alternative?

Comment: I don't know of any alternatives (I am not very familiar with pig or cassandra). I would recommend sticking with the latest version that has the class you need (if possible), otherwise you could go to the github for cassandra and get the classes you need and maintain it yourself. If you do this, I would also recommend making it open source in case others would find it useful as well.  :)